# How to tell composer to also checkout the submoduled components?

Tags: json, git, installation, composer-php, git-submodules

I'm new in composer and git. I recently created a project forked then created a submoduled on it. In composer, I was able to get the forked project but it did not get the submoduled component. How am I going to tell composer that it should also install/get the submoduled component of my project.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have forked the [composer repo](https://github.com/composer/composer) and made a submodule in it, then you would need a:

```
git submodule update --init
```

That would populate the submodule you have declared in it.